# Accessing files on iPhone from Linux/CentOS (Where are the APP's)

Tags: centos, files, application, iphone

https://libimobiledevice.org/
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=78621

According to CentOS 8

```
libimobiledevice
    # dnf install libimobiledevice
    https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/libimobiledevice-1.2.0-16.el8.x86_64.rpm
    https://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/AppStream/Source/SPackages/libimobiledevice-1.2.0-16.el8.src.rpm

libplist
    # dnf install libplist
    https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/libplist-2.0.0-10.el8.x86_64.rpm
    https://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/AppStream/Source/SPackages/libplist-2.0.0-10.el8.src.rpm

libusbmuxd
    # dnf install libusbmuxd
    https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/libusbmuxd-1.0.10-9.el8.x86_64.rpm
    https://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/AppStream/Source/SPackages/libusbmuxd-1.0.10-9.el8.src.rpm

ifuse

    Download latest epel-release rpm from
    http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/
    Install epel-release rpm:
    # rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm
    Install ifuse rpm package:
    # dnf install ifuse
    https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/i/ifuse-1.1.3-17.el8.x86_64.rpm
    https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/SRPMS/Packages/i/ifuse-1.1.3-17.el8.src.rpm

usbmuxd
    # dnf install usbmuxd
    https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/usbmuxd-1.1.0-13.el8.x86_64.rpm
    https://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/AppStream/Source/SPackages/usbmuxd-1.1.0-13.el8.src.rpm
```

AVAILABLE ON CENTOS

libimobiledevice 1.3.0

usbmuxd 1.1.1

- ideviceinstaller 1.1.1 (CENTOS 8 NOT)
- idevicerestore 1.0.0 (CENTOS 8 NOT)

ifuse 1.1.4

libusbmuxd 2.0.2

libplist 2.2.0

- libirecovery 1.0.0 (CENTOS 8 NOT)
- libideviceactivation 1.1.1 (CENTOS 8 NOT)

I get some RPM's from https://pkgs.org/search/

List RPM's

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [root@centos libimobiledevice_AccessToIPhone]# ls -al
    total 308
    drwxrwxr-x.  2 joseluisbz joseluisbz  4096 Mar 16 12:23 .
    drwxrwxrwx. 17 joseluisbz joseluisbz  4096 Mar 16 12:21 ..
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 joseluisbz joseluisbz 34500 Mar 16 12:22 ifuse-1.1.3-17.el8.x86_64.rpm
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 joseluisbz joseluisbz 81616 Mar 16 12:20 libimobiledevice-1.2.0-16.el8.x86_64.rpm
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 joseluisbz joseluisbz 79296 Mar 16 12:21 libplist-2.0.0-10.el8.x86_64.rpm
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 joseluisbz joseluisbz 35616 Mar 16 12:22 libusbmuxd-1.0.10-9.el8.x86_64.rpm
    -rw-rw-r--.  1 joseluisbz joseluisbz 66384 Mar 16 12:23 usbmuxd-1.1.0-13.el8.x86_64.rpm
    [root@centos libimobiledevice_AccessToIPhone]#
```

INSTALL

```
rpm -i ifuse-1.1.3-17.el8.x86_64.rpm libimobiledevice-1.2.0-16.el8.x86_64.rpm libplist-2.0.0-10.el8.x86_64.rpm libusbmuxd-1.0.10-9.el8.x86_64.rpm usbmuxd-1.1.0-13.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

RESULT (Previous DONE)

```
[root@centos libimobiledevice_AccessToIPhone]# rpm -i ifuse-1.1.3-17.el8.x86_64.rpm libimobiledevice-1.2.0-16.el8.x86_64.rpm libplist-2.0.0-10.el8.x86_64.rpm libusbmuxd-1.0.10-9.el8.x86_64.rpm usbmuxd-1.1.0-13.el8.x86_64.rpm
    package libplist-2.0.0-10.el8.x86_64 is already installed
    package libusbmuxd-1.0.10-9.el8.x86_64 is already installed
    package libimobiledevice-1.2.0-16.el8.x86_64 is already installed
    package usbmuxd-1.1.0-13.el8.x86_64 is already installed
[root@centos libimobiledevice_AccessToIPhone]#
```

[root@centos ~]# exit

MOUNT FILES

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ mkdir ~/phone
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ ifuse ~/phone
```

Check Files with LS

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ ls -al ~/phone
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  15 joseluisbz joseluisbz  480 Mar 16 06:50 .
drwxrwxrwx.  36 joseluisbz joseluisbz 4096 Mar 16 13:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x.   3 joseluisbz joseluisbz   96 Jan 22  2019 AirFair
drwxr-xr-x.   8 joseluisbz joseluisbz  256 Nov  7 22:42 Books
drwxr-xr-x.  35 joseluisbz joseluisbz 1120 Mar 14 18:19 DCIM
drwxr-xr-x.   5 joseluisbz joseluisbz  160 Mar 15 18:13 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x.   3 joseluisbz joseluisbz   96 Aug 11  2021 EnhancedAudioSharedKeys
drwxr-xr-x.   6 joseluisbz joseluisbz  192 Jan 22  2019 iTunes_Control
drwxr-xr-x.   6 joseluisbz joseluisbz  192 Mar 12 08:29 MediaAnalysis
drwxr-xr-x.  30 joseluisbz joseluisbz  960 Mar 16 06:52 PhotoData
drwxr-xr-x.   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   64 Jan 18  2020 Photos
drwxr-xr-x.   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   64 Nov 15  2018 PublicStaging
drwxr-xr-x.   2 joseluisbz joseluisbz   64 Dec 22  2018 Purchases
drwxr-xr-x.   5 joseluisbz joseluisbz  160 Sep 19  2019 Radio
drwxr-xr-x. 200 joseluisbz joseluisbz 6400 Feb 24 15:02 Recordings
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

Check files

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ tree -L 1 ~/phone
/home/joseluisbz/phone
├── AirFair
├── Books
├── DCIM
├── Downloads
├── EnhancedAudioSharedKeys
├── iTunes_Control
├── MediaAnalysis
├── PhotoData
├── Photos
├── PublicStaging
├── Purchases
├── Radio
└── Recordings

13 directories, 0 files
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

In order to unmount

```
fusermount -u ~/phone
```

**Where I can get/review my apps in my iPhone?**

Comment: On an iPhone you don't have access to system directories.

Comment: https://evanwill.github.io/_drafts/notes/iphone-transfer.html   -  https://command-not-found.com/ideviceinfo - https://command-not-found.com/mount.fuse